# Re-Write url? Syntax?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I was working on a website for a client. I wanted to re-write a url but don't know how to go about it. I have very less time. I am looking for a tutorial, but would be quite helpful if someone could help me.

Following is the url that I receive:

www.example.com/shop/url_encoded_category_name/product?productid=

I want to re-write it to:

www.example.com/shop-public-home.php?productid=

The problem here is that "url_encoded_category_name" will be some text and will be something different every time.

I am looking for a quick tutorial, and will close the question if I found a solution.

I am highly thankful for any help you can provide.

Jehanzeb k. Malik

Comment: What system / environment? That is what http server? What modules available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably use apache mod_rewrite, if you use an apache http server. All apache modules have excellent documentation including good examples. You will find all details you are looking for in that documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You can either setup the rewriting rules in the central server configuration (preferred way) or decentralized using so called ".htaccess" files. You can use more or less the same rules for both approaches. Check the `RewriteEngine`, `RewriteRule`, `RewriteMap` and `RewriteCond` commands.

Comment: Thanks. I already had setup an htaccess file. I just was having problem with the syntax of rewriting. But I found out this detailed tutorial at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/. I fixed my rewrite syntax and it works now.

Thanks for the help though!